# How to compare two files and produce a third file where all differences are replaced by a marker?

Tags: diff

What I am looking for is similar to a usual **diff** between files A and B, but that prints out a file C which comprises the common content from A and B, but also the diferences (replaced by some marker, e.g., §§§§ like shown below).

**File A:**

```
brown fox 
lazy dog 
both moving
1
2
3
```

**File B:**

```
RED fox 
lazy dog 
OUCH, GONE 
ARE, BACK
1
3
```

**Resulting file C:**

```
§§§ fox 
lazy dog
§§§§§§§§§§
§§§§§§§§§
1
§
3
```

I managed to tell *diff* how to do half of the solution with **diff A B -tyd**:

```
brown fox                                                       |  RED fox 
lazy dog                                                           lazy dog 
both moving                                                     |  OUCH, GONE 
                                                                >  ARE, BACK
1                                                                  1
2                                                               <
3                                                                  3
```

However, a direct comparison between the columns is still needed. I could consider each word as a line and feed *diff* again, or use some regex command to make the comparisons and substitutions.
I am pretty sure there is a standard way to do that, since several software are able to do diffs that consider intraline differences (e.g. Intellij Idea, Overleaf):
[image]

Whitespaces as word boundaries are not necessarily relevant, as shown in the picture.

Another partial solution is to use **wdiff b a -n**:

```
[-RED-]{+brown+} fox 
lazy dog 
[-OUCH, GONE -]
[-ARE, BACK-] 
{+both moving+}
1
{+2+}
3
```

Comment: I understand what you are looking for, but for an algorithm it's far from being obvious what is a change, a deletion, an insertion. Perhaps line 4 was changed from `1` to `ARE, BACK` and line 5 from `2` to `1` -- no deletions or insertions. There are always several possibilities to make files fit and no simple attempt will filfill your needs.

Comment: I agree with @Philippos, following your description, there is no single correct solution.

Comment: @Philippos You are correct, my first attempt of file C was undecidable. I will post half the way to the solution using diff.